# C++ Constructor not calling

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include<iostream>  
using namespace std;  
class base {  
public:     
    base() {
        cout<<"Constructing base \n";
    }  
    virtual ~base() {
        cout<<"Destructing base \n";
    } 
};  
class derived: public base { 
public:    
    derived() {
        cout<<"Constructing derived \n";
    }    
    ~derived() {
        cout<<"Destructing derived \n";
    }
};   
int main(void) {
    derived d();     
    return 0; 
}
```

Why in this program its not calling constructor?

Can Anyone explain?
.......

Comment: please intent your code properly.

Comment: You should call base() ctor in derived(). derived() : base() { cout << "Constructing derived"; }

Comment: uhm...Most vexing parse again.

Comment: `derived d();` does _not_ define a variable, it _declares a function_ (taking no parameter and returning a `derived`). See [Variable Initialization](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/001.htm) and [Variable Initialization – or Is It?](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/). @bkausbk Not needed, it's done implicitly by the compiler.

Comment: @gx_: You are right :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are declaring a function here:

```
// function d(), returns a derived object.
derived d();
```

What you need is

```
derived d; // C++03, C++11
```

or

```
derived d{}; // C++11 only
```

This is an "interesting" aspect of C++, where anything that can be parsed as a function declaration will be (provided it is in a context where a function can be declared).

See more on variable initialization in [GoTW #1 Variable initialization - or is it?](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/).

Comment: does he get a warning? for this

Comment: I've seen warnings for this in VS2012

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I don't get warnings on the platform I am on now (an ancient version of GCC),

Comment: If you've got access to C++11 you can do `derived d{};`

Comment: @ juanchopanza correct  it shouldn't warn t because its a correct declaration e.g `int d();`

Comment: @MarkIngram I was just adding that :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan There are lots and lots of compiler warnings about code that is strictly speaking correct, but probably not what the author wanted. The Most Vexing Parse is just another such case: function declarations inside another function are rarely useful, and so there's a good chance that the user meant to create an object. Clang warns about this, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
int main(void) {  
    derived d;     
    return 0; 
}
```

When you type `derived d()` you are declaring a function and not creating object.

Comment: Or use `derived d{};` (c++11)

Answer (score 3):

Declaration not proper for `derived d();`

Change it to:

```
int main(void) 
{
  derived d;     // note the difference     
  return 0; 
}
```

What you are doing -> `derived d()`, **it declares a function.** that **returns instance of derived class.**

See this for details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Answer (score 2):

It is because `derived d()` is treated as "function d, called without any arguments, returning instance of derived". Google 'most vexing parse'.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(void)
{  
    derived d();     //here you are actually declaring a function
    return 0; 
}
```

You should do it like this:

```
derived d;
```

Then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, before a compiler calls a function, it must be aware of the function. Either you need to write the function in the flow before it is called or it should at least be declared before the function is called. So by calling `derived d()` you have declared a function called `d()` with return type as derived object, you never created `derived` object. it should have been like,

```
int main() {
   derived d;
   return 0

}
```